# Associativity and Precedence in C

Tags: c, operator-keyword, operator-precedence, associativity

i) What does if(0) mean?

Everytime I use it to test what output i will get, it returns the false part.

Is it equivalent to if(0 == 0), incase of which the true part is evaluated.

ii) Associativity of logical NOT ! is right to left.

Link: http://www.liv.ac.uk/HPC/HTMLF90Course/HTMLF90CourseNotesnode94.html

The second example in the link of logical operators:

But as per the line "the two subexpressions containing the monadic .NOT. are effectively evaluated first, as there are two of these the leftmost, .NOT.A is done first followed by .NOT.E.", the left NOT is evaluated first, but the first one to be evaluated should be the one on the right...???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I**) In C, 0 is false and everything else is true. So with `if (0)`, the condition will always be false and the body will never be executed because 0 is always false.

`if (0 == 0)` is completely different because 0 does in fact equal zero, and the expression `0 == 0` evaluates to true, so the body of the `if` is executed.

**II**) The associativity of operators determines what happens when you have ambiguities from multiple operators of the same precedence. For instance, what should happen in `a - b - c`? Should the `b - c` be evaluated first or the `a - b`? It *does* matter what order you do them in, because if a = 1, b = 2, and c = 3, `a - (b - c)` is `2`, but `(a - b) - c` is -4. But because subtraction is left-associative, we can know that `a - b` will be evaluated first, so the answer to `a - b - c` is -4 when a = 1, b = 2, c = 3.

All that being said, I can't think of a case where the associativity of the logical not operator would matter, and the associativity of an operator does not determine what order it will be executed in when it is seperated by operators of different precedence.

Comment: The question was about C, not C++.

Comment: @WTP whoops, I think I fixed it. Does everything still apply now?

Comment: It's not just that the subtraction must be done left to right, it's also that arithmetic operators of the same precedence level must be logically evaluated left to right. The reason for that is default promotions of operands. The sum `1+UINT_MAX+1.0` will differ from `1+1.0+UINT_MAX`. The first sum evaluates as `(1+UINT_MAX)+1.0` and equals `1.0`. The second evaluates as `(1+1.0)+UINT_MAX` and equals the double of `2+UINT_MAX`. If ints are 16-bit, you get `1.0` and `65537.0` respectively. If ints are 32-bit, you get `1.0` and `4294967297.0`. Try with your compiler.

Comment: @user980411 I changed "In C++" to "In C" and removed "with intrinsic types"

Comment: @Alex I think I indicated that in my answer with the line "when you have ambiguities from multiple operators of the same precedence" but if it's ambiguous, let me know.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Missed it. Should serve as a good example nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

i) in C, 0 mean false, so `if(0)` will always jump to the `else` (if there).
it is the opposite of `if(0==0)`, (or simply `if(1)`), which will do the true part.

Answer (score 0):

`if (0)` evaluates the predicate `0` as a binary value. Binary values in C use integers, where zero means false and non-zero means true. Therefore, 0 will always evaluate to false.

For binary operators, being right- or left-associative determines the order that otherwise equally important operators will be processed. Consider the subtraction operator:

```
37 - 10 - 4
```

Both `-` are equal precedence so which should we evaluate first? Well, `-` is left-associative so we do:

```
(37 - 10) - 4 ==> (27) - 4 ==> 23
```

If the `-` operator were right-associative, we would do:

```
37 - (10 - 4) ==> 37 - 6 ==> 31
```

Equality (`=`) is right-associative because we might chain equalities together. So, if we see

```
// a and b are initialized to 0
a = b = 45
```

Both `=` are equal precedence so we evaluate right to left and do:

```
a = (b = 45) // b receives 45
a = 45       // a receives 45
```

If we were to go left-right, we'd get an unexpected result:

```
(a = b) = 45 // a receives 0
b = 45       // b receives 45
```

For unary operators, however, ordering can only matter when multiple unary operators affect the same value. For example, let's do:

```
char x = 0xFF
bool y = !~x
```

These unary operators are right-associative, so we do:

```
!(~0xFF) ==> !(0x0) ==> true
```

In the example you showed, the negation operators affecting `A` and `E` didn't have "equal precedence" because they didn't have the same operand. So, associativity doesn't apply.

Comment: Associativity of NOT is given as right to left in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence. That means in case of two operators having the same precedence, the rightmost will be executed first...?

Comment: @user980411 yes but only if they are not seperated by operators of different precedence does associativity matter (I think). I don't know where the associativity of a unary operator could matter.

Comment: @user980411 right-associative means the `not` operator associates with the item on its right. That's why we write `!false` instead of `false!`. It doesn't mean `!a + !b` must have the `b` evaluated before the `a`.

Comment: @RobertMartin are you sure that's what right-associative means? For instance, the `=` operator is also right-associative.

Comment: What I said is only true for unary operators. I'll update my answer to include right-associative for binary operators.

Comment: Just emphasizing something RobertMartin says in passing: associativity and evaluation order are completely different concepts; knowing what the associativity is doesn't tell you what the evaluation order is. In fact, many times the associativity will be exactly defined but the eval order won't be. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395423 (and many other questions about sequence points).